# Android ListView NullPointerException using pulldowntoRefresh?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, nullpointerexception

I am using a pull TO Refresh Libary: https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

Logcat gives me NullPointerExcetpion (I think at line 77).
 PLease help, I would be really happy to solve this problem.

I think the problem is with the array, adapter.

**UPDATE1**

I changed the xml file id to : android:id="@+id/list" 
and i also changed it correctly in java file.
now it shows a new error:

***Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'***

```
05-25 16:17:32.730: D/dalvikvm(29170): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 20% free 8477K/10508K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
05-25 16:17:32.730: I/dalvikvm-heap(29170): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.708MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-25 16:17:32.745: D/dalvikvm(29170): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 12077K/14112K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-25 16:17:32.855: D/dalvikvm(29170): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 12076K/14112K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
05-25 16:17:32.855: I/dalvikvm-heap(29170): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.771MB for 14745616-byte allocation
05-25 16:17:32.870: D/dalvikvm(29170): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 26476K/28516K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-25 16:17:32.975: D/AbsListView(29170): Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-25 16:17:32.985: D/ProgressBar(29170): setProgress = 0
05-25 16:17:32.985: D/ProgressBar(29170): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
05-25 16:17:32.985: D/ProgressBar(29170): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
05-25 16:17:32.995: D/AndroidRuntime(29170): Shutting down VM
05-25 16:17:32.995: W/dalvikvm(29170): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42466700)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scapp2014.seoul.zeisler.tripathi/com.scapp2014.seoul.zeisler.tripathi.parsingXML}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:364)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at com.scapp2014.seoul.zeisler.tripathi.parsingXML.onCreate(parsingXML.java:44)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
05-25 16:17:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(29170):    ... 11 more




main.xml:

xmlParsing:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />



    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->

    <eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#b5b4b4" />

</RelativeLayout>


    package com.scapp2014.seoul.zeisler.tripathi;

    public class parsingXML extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=02df7ff302bb81e1944ad00f28a6a3b3&_render=rss";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "pubDate";

    private PullToRefreshListView listView;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listView.onRefreshComplete();
                    }
                }, 50);
            }
        });




        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE) );
            map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AUTHOR)) ;
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC) + "\n");
            map.put(KEY_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE) );

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list,
                new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_AUTHOR, KEY_DATE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title, R.id.description, R.id.author, R.id.date });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                String author = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();
                String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), singleGUI.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                in.putExtra(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, date);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });




    } // end of main



    }
```

Comment: Posting your logcat would be helpful.

Comment: i did. please help. iw ill be the happiest person if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are extending ListActivity, you should reference your listview by:

```
//listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.layout.list);
listview = getListView();
```

Comment: in the xml file it says:

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'id' with value '+@id/
 list').

Comment: yes i did that thanks. now it only shows a new eror:

Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: please help, i will mark your answer. i will be very happy if you could help me, i am a student... pleaseee

Comment: answer updated, didn't realize you are extending ListActivity, change back your listview's id in xml to android:id="@android:id/list" and reference it as stated in the answer.

Comment: thank you. you are awsesome, you are the best programmer i have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

If you use listActivity you have to change the id of the listView in the XML like this:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

And in your activity you get the list like SteD said:

```
listview = getListView();
```